# Upper bound for a squared zero-mean sub-Gaussian random variable: Transforming a sub-Gaussian rv to a a Gaussian rv

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions, distribution-tails

I'm studying from the book "Mathematical Analysis of Machine Learning Algorithms" by Tong Zhang. Theorem 2.9 states

> Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^N$ be independent zero-mean sub-Gaussian random variables that satisfy
> $$
> \ln\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X_n)] \leq \frac{\lambda^2 b_n}{2},
> $$
> then for $\lambda < \frac{1}{2}b_n$ we have
> $$
> \ln\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X_n^2)] \leq -\frac{1}{2}\ln(1 - 2\lambda b_n) \tag{1}
> $$
> [+ some other terms]

To prove (1) above, the author writes

**proof** Let $\xi\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ which is independent of $X_n$. Then, for all $\lambda b_n <0.5$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Lambda_{X_n^2} &= \ln\mathbb{E}_{X_n}[\exp(\lambda X_n^2)]\\
&= \ln\mathbb{E}_{X_n}\mathbb{E}_\xi[\exp(\sqrt{2\lambda}\xi X_n)]\\
&= ...
\end{aligned}\tag{2}
$$

The second line in (2) it's what I'm interested in. I can't seem to understand how to transform a sub-Gaussian random variable to a Gaussian random variable. At the bottom of the proof the author writes: "The second [...] equality can be obtained using Gaussian integration", but the most I've been able to write is

$$
\ln\mathbb{E}_{X_n^{(1)}}\left[\int \exp\left(
[\lambda^{1/2}X_n^{(1)}][\lambda^{1/2}X_n^{(2)}] \mathbb{1}(X_n^{(1)} - X_n^{(2)} =0) p(X_n^{(2)}) dX_n^{(2)},
\right)\right].
$$

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: The second line follows from the fact that $E_{\xi}e^{t\xi}=e^{t^{2}/2}$ (and independence of $\xi$ and $X_n$).

Comment: What the author wrote at the bottom of the proof has nothing to do with the second line of (2).

Comment: @geetha290krm, I had a typo. The author wrote: "second equality", which does happen to be the second line in $(2)$

Comment: Do you understand what conditioning on $X_n$ means? You are making things too complicated. The second line of (2) is quite trivial if you know the formula I wrote in my first comment.